# Change Rate-Us URL remotely without updating the app Android

Tags: json, android-studio, url, remote-server, auto-update

I want to use a Json file, when i click on a button to rate the app, the URL will be in a Json file Online, so i can any time change it without updating the app from the market.
Is there any example for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check/use the [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android) to define parameters in your app and update their values in the cloud, allowing you to modify the appearance and behavior of your app without distributing an app update.

Here's a [Sample App Walkthrough](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/android) from them on how to use the Firebase Remote Config.

Comment: Is there any other way instead of using firebase ?

Comment: @Cristina99 Does your app uses REST api web service? Or do you have a REST web service? If you have, then you can expose an endpoint for getting the rate URL config/data. If you don't have, you may upload a public .json file somewhere, if incase you don't want to do that, then I suggest use firebase.

Comment: i want to use json, but i'm not good at programming, that's why i'm looking for some kind of existing example to use.